# Vaadin Authentication and Auhorization

Tags: vaadin, jaas

I'm new to Vaadin.
Before this I made a JSF Web Application.
I had a ManagedBean performing the login of the user. I used a security-realm to delegate the actual verification of the credentials.

How do I do this in Vaadin? Is there a best practice?
I'm at a point where I would just put something together, but there has to be some kind of standard-procedure, shouldn't it!?
I found some tutorials on this, but mostly using Spring (I want to use EJB).
Also, every tutorial seemed unneccessary complicated.

There has to be some simple+conclusive tutorial for something so common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the only Vaadin official article about how to secure a [Vaadin aplication using JAAS](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/using-vaadin-cdi-with-jaas-authentication) that I could find. I mean native or official Vaadin Securization. You will find more if you google a little bit with Spring security, Shiro, but pure ESB uses JAAS.
I agree that this article is not enough to learn how to set up an application. I share here my experience:

**1. Vaadin CDI extension:**

```
<!-- Vaadin Official DI support. -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
  <artifactId>vaadin-cdi</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.alpha2</version>
</dependency>
```

**2. Understanding about JAAS**

I suggest you to have a look how JAAS works in a non-vaadin application, by reading overview articles, because JAAS depends on Server application provider (TomEE,Jboss, Wildfly, Glasfish) all have different configuration settings.
Here you will find a [proof of concept](https://github.com/antoniomaria/jaas-basic-auth) using Tomee.

**3. Developing your own Login Module.**

If you have decided to create a custom login module for example:

```
public class MyLoginModule implements LoginModule {
private CallbackHandler handler;
private Subject subject;
private UserPrincipal userPrincipal;
private RolePrincipal rolePrincipal;
private String login;
private List<String> userGroups;
@Override
public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler, Map<String, ?> sharedState,
Map<String, ?> options) {
handler = callbackHandler;
this.subject = subject;
}
@Override
public boolean login() throws LoginException {
Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[2];
callbacks[0] = new NameCallback("login");
callbacks[1] = new PasswordCallback("password", true);
try {
handler.handle(callbacks);
String name = ((NameCallback) callbacks[0]).getName();
String password = String.valueOf(((PasswordCallback) callbacks[1]).getPassword());
// Here we validate the credentials against some
// authentication/authorization provider.
// It can be a Database, an external LDAP, a Web Service, etc.
// For this tutorial we are just checking if user is "user123" and
// password is "pass123"
if (name != null && name.equals("admin") && password != null && password.equals("admin")) {
login = name;
userGroups = new ArrayList<String>();
userGroups.add("admin");
return true;
}
// If credentials are NOT OK we throw a LoginException
throw new LoginException("Authentication failed");
} catch (IOException e) {
throw new LoginException(e.getMessage());
} catch (UnsupportedCallbackException e) {
throw new LoginException(e.getMessage());
}
}
@Override
public boolean commit() throws LoginException {
userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(login);
subject.getPrincipals().add(userPrincipal);
if (userGroups != null && userGroups.size() > 0) {
for (String groupName : userGroups) {
rolePrincipal = new RolePrincipal(groupName);
subject.getPrincipals().add(rolePrincipal);
}
}
return true;
}
@Override
public boolean abort() throws LoginException {
return false;
}
@Override
public boolean logout() throws LoginException {
subject.getPrincipals().remove(userPrincipal);
subject.getPrincipals().remove(rolePrincipal);
return true;
}
}
```

Reference it in the META-INF/context.xml of your application. This settings are for TomEE, but for glashfish or other must be similar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm" appName="myrealm" userClassNames="net.sf.jaas.auth.UserPrincipal"
    roleClassNames="net.sf.jaas.auth.RolePrincipal" />
</Context>
```

**Be aware that userClassNames and roleClassNames are just simple Java Pojo but must implement java.security.Principal;**

**3. Enabling JAAS into your Vaadin Login View**

Define your favourite login form, using Vaadin TextField and Password, and define in your doLoginEvent() a references to JAAS. 
Whenever JaasAccessControl.login is called, a new instance of your LoginModule will be created.

```
  import com.vaadin.cdi.access.JaasAccessControl;
  try {
            JaasAccessControl.login(loginEvent.getUsername(), loginEvent.getPassword());
            logger.info("User {} authenticated", getPrincipalName());
            navigator.navigateTo(Main.NAME);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Notification.show("Error logging in", Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

**4. Using information of your logged user.**

Whenever a user passes the JAAS login filter. It will be available in his request context a class that identifies him. This class is called Principal (the one you have previously set in the LoginModule class).

```
public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        return JaasAccessControl.getCurrentRequest().isUserInRole(role);
    }

    public String getPrincipalName() {
        Principal principal = JaasAccessControl.getCurrentRequest().getUserPrincipal();
        if (principal != null) {
            return principal.getName();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public boolean isUserSignedIn() {
        Principal principal = JaasAccessControl.getCurrentRequest().getUserPrincipal();
        return principal != null;
    }
```

**5. Alternatives to LoginModule**

It's not mandatory to create your custom login Module, normally the Java EE providers as Tomee supply few implementation. Authentication based on properties file, in some database tables.
Have a look on [Tomee documentation JAAS](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-jaas.html) to see some examples:

**6. Enable JAAS in TomEE**
You need to create a jaas.config file which references you LoginModule, for example:

```
filename: jaas.config 
myrealm{
    net.sf.jaas.MyLoginModule required;
};
```

Then start the application server with this parameter:

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=E:/apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.6.0.2/conf/jaas.config
```

If you want to have a look a proof of concept of this. [Checkout this example](https://github.com/antoniomaria/gazpachoquest/tree/master/questionnaires-ui), which uses Tomee, Vaadin 7, JAAS,

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problem a couple of months ago. I wasn't then able to figure out how it really works, so I went over the spring adddon and now I'm using a Vaadin login form and spring security

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll leave this question open though, because somebody might come up with a pure Vaadin solution.

Answer (score 1):

A full example that uses JAAS, Vaadin 8, Vaadin CDI add-on and the built-in `LoginForm` is available [here](https://github.com/mrts/vaadin-javaee-jaas-example), steps are as follows:

1. Enable the Vaadin CDI add-on in `pom.xml`
2. Enable [CDI in Vaadin UI](https://github.com/mrts/vaadin-javaee-jaas-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jaasexample/JaasExampleUI.java) with `@CDIUI` annotation and configure the `Navigator`
3. Enable [authorization in a CDI view](https://github.com/mrts/vaadin-javaee-jaas-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jaasexample/SecureView.java) by adding the `@RolesAllowed` annotation (or any other `javax.annotation.security` annotation)
4. Implement [a login view](https://github.com/mrts/vaadin-javaee-jaas-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jaasexample/LoginView.java) that derives from the built-in `LoginForm` and uses `JaasAccessControl` to authenticate the user.

It is actually a rather nice, fluent experience once you figure out how the pieces fit together.

There's a longer article in [Vaadin wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+Vaadin+CDI+with+JAAS+authentication) that explains how to use database-backed authentication with JAAS.